# Processmaker 4 Script editor produces no output when I run a PHP script

Tags: processmaker

I am trying to write a PHP script for a scripted task in Processmaker 4. All the documentation and videos I have seen state that if you press the run button it should run the script an display the output, but when I run it, I can see the docker container being created, running and then disappearing but no output is displayed in the Processmaker Script Editor. It seems like the editor never really realizes that the script has fished executing. The Run buttone remains dissabled so I can not run the script again, no output appears in the output section of the editor, and I get a rotating progress icon in the lower right corner of the editor (see screen capture with comments).

[image]

Any suggestion of what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using Processmaker 4.2.34. In my case, the container not even started. I switch to Processmaker 4.1.21, and everything works fine.

Comment: In my case I am already running 4.1.21 .... Sor some reason running the scripts is working interminently ... sometimes it works fine but others it just stalls  forever...

Comment: For some reason it worked for some time but now it is not working again. The executor docker container gets created and I see it apearing and executing in docker but the output never gets back to processmaker and the docker container is never removed. :-(